# What is computed by LinearAlgebra`Private`MatrixConditionNumber?

Tags: linear-algebra, undocumented

The following returns 51/7, even though the condition number is actually 9. I'm curious, what does 51/7 correspond to for this matrix?

```
LinearAlgebra`Private`MatrixConditionNumber[{{7, 0, 0}, {0, 5, 4}, {0, 4, 5}}]
```

Wolfram Alpha returns the same result for the condition number of this matrix, as mentioned in this [Twitter post](https://twitter.com/konstmish/status/1743308200659533967).

Comment: It's an exact version of the infinity norm condition number estimate used by `LUDecomposition`: `In[292]:= 
LUDecomposition[{{7, 0, 0}, {0, 5, 4}, {0, 4., 5}}][[3]] - 51/7

Out[292]= 8.88178*10^-16`

Comment: @DanielLichtblau hm...shouldn't infinity condition  also be 9? `A = {{7, 0, 0}, {0, 5, 4}, {0, 4, 5}}; Norm[A, Infinity]/Norm[Inverse[A], Infinity]`

Comment: The actual value is 9, yes. The estimate is from an iteration, I believe due to N. Higham. It does not compute an inverse or do any other O(n^3) operation, hence saves an order of magnitude in speed.

Comment: Just to compare. Maple's `LinearAlgebra:-ConditionNumber(Matrix([[7, 0, 0], [0, 5, 4], [0, 4, 5]]))` returns `9`.

Comment: Just to compare. Octave/MATLAB's `A = [7, 0, 0; 0, 5, 4; 0, 4, 5];
condition_number = cond(A);
disp(condition_number);` returns `9`

Comment: I believe LAPACK's [?gecond](https://www.netlib.org/lapack//explore-html/d4/daf/group__gecon.html) is being used. FORTRAN code may be inspected; it's an iterative approximation as @Daniel mentions. W|A often does math over floating-point even when the input looks like exact integers to Mma users. Not sure the blame should be on W|A, since LAPACK is used widely by many different applications.

Comment: Just to compare: MATLAB `1/rcond(A)` returns `7.285714285714286`. On a 10000 x 10000 matrix, `rcond` takes 5.2 sec.; `cond(mat, 1)` and `cond(mat, inf)` take about 13 sec. while `cond(mat)` (2-norm) takes nearly 33 sec.

Comment: @Goofy why do you think it's gecond? I'm seeing 9 using gecond through scipy lapack wrapper -- `import scipy
1/scipy.linalg.lapack.dgecon([[7.,0,0],[0,5,4],[0,4,5]], anorm=9, norm='I')[0]`

Comment: I guess because I've read on MathWorks.com that Matlab uses DGECON, and it agreed with Mma. And the description of DGECON matched what @Daniel said. Note the input to DGECON is supposed to be the output of DGETRF, not the matrix itself. You can see if that makes a difference. I don't know how scipy works.

Comment: @Goofy ah, yes, if I use output of dgetrf I get 51/7, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extrapolating from how Matlab does it in comments, you also get $51/7$ from Lapack's `dgecon` applied to LU factorization of mat (`dgetrf`)

```
import scipy
mat=[[7.,0,0],[0,5,4],[0,4,5]]
lu=scipy.linalg.lapack.dgetrf(mat)[0]
eigs=scipy.linalg.eigh(mat)[0]
1/scipy.linalg.lapack.dgecon(lu, anorm=max(eigs), norm='I')[0] # 7.2857142857142865
```